# c#: Stack stops at Invoke

Tags: c#, tcp, controls, invoke

In C#/.net, when an error occurs, the stack is logged in the windows error logs. However, my application has a lot of cross thread invokes. The Stack trace seems to stop at every Invoke(MarshalledInvoke).

for example:

**my stack:**

```
Exception Info: Facebook.FacebookApiException
Stack:
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])
at Test.TcpTest.InterpretData()
at Test.TcpTest.Incoming(System.String)
at Test.TcpTest.cLoop()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The exception occurs in code being executed further in the stack. However, the stack stops at a marshalledInvoke every time.

Is there something i can do to continue the stack on an invoke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use Control.Invoke() instead of Control.BeginInvoke() then any exception that is raised on the UI thread is marshaled back to your worker thread and re-thrown.  There is some loss of information, you get the inner-most exception.

Using Invoke() is very rarely correct and is generally harmful for its potential to cause deadlock, obfuscate exceptions and delay your worker thread.  Which is blocked until the UI thread has executed the delegate target.  That can take a while.  Do make sure that you actually require it.  Which is only truly necessary if you invoke a method whose return value you need.  This should always be avoided.

You can debug these exceptions with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR Exceptions.  The debugger will now stop at the code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Im using the invokes to stop "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" errors. Would using delegate.invoke/begininvoke also work for these exceptions?

Comment: No, a delegate's BeginInvoke method runs code on a separate worker thread.  this is explicitly **not** what you want to do, you want to run code on the UI thread to avoid the "Cross-thread" exception.